# How to add a general title with a seaborn.objects.Plot.facet plot

Tags: python, seaborn, seaborn-0.12.x

I am currently using the seaborn library in Python to create a facetted stacked barplot from a pandas dataframe named `averages` with columns `['Name', 'Period', 'Value', 'Solver']`.

Here is the code I use to create the plot I want.

```
p = so.Plot(data = averages, x = 'Period', y = 'Value', color = 'Name').add(so.Bar(), so.Stack(), suptitle='Inventory levels')
p = p.facet(col='Solver', order=['spse', 'mp2', 'mels'])
```

I am searching for a way to add a general title to the plot *i.e.* a title above each subplot, like the function `matplotlib.pyplot.suptitle` function does for example.

I know that the function `seaborn.objects.Plot.label` has a `title=` option, but when I use it, this puts the same title above each subplot of the facetted graph.

Comment: To clarify, do you want (1) one title for the general figure, or (2) one title for each subplot, i.e. appearing multiple times, or (3) different titles for each subplot, i.e. multiple titles of different text?

Comment: The first option is what I want to achieve. The second is what I get with the ```title=``` option mentionned in the post. For the third, I think there is a seaborn documentation page that explains how to do it with the same ```title=``` option

Comment: In this case, my answer allow should work, right? I am afraid using purely the `seaborn.objects` interface is not supported for this yet.

Comment: Yes it seems to work. I had the same conclusion for the interface, I think tthe documpentation mentions it is not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an existing Matplotlib figure or axes for drawing the plot using [`so.Plot.on`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.objects.Plot.on.html). This gives you access to the underlying `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object to which the suptitle can be added.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn.objects as so
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "y": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16],
    "group": ["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b"],
})

fig = plt.Figure()
fig.suptitle("Suptitle")

(
    so.Plot(df, x="x", y="y")
    .add(so.Line())
    .facet(col="group")
    .on(fig)
    .plot()
)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work, however I can't figure how to display the figure. I tried your code and added a ```.show()``` (after the ```.plot()``` and without it) but the graph is not displayed. Do you have a hint for it ?

Comment: @Haeden What is your environment (i.e. a regular python script, a Jupyter notebook, etc.)?

Comment: I am on Visual Studio Code

Comment: @Haeden In a python or Jupyter file?

Comment: In a regular python file